# Twitter search API results

Tags: twitter

I'm using the Twitter API atom format

`http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=Name&:)&since:year-month-date&rpp=1500`

but it's only returning 100 tweets, I tried using the JSON format as well, but it only returned 100 results. Is there anything that I'm doing wrong to only get 100 results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're limited on the number of results per page. In order to get more results, you have to use the `page` parameter like so:

http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=Name&:)&since:year-month-date&rpp=1500&page=2

***EDIT***

> rpp: the number of tweets to return
>   per page, up to a max of 100. E.g.,
>
> http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?lang=en&q=devo&rpp=15
>
> page: the page number to return, up to
>   a max of roughly 1500 results (based
>   on rpp * page)

Source: http://search.twitter.com/api/

In other words your `rpp` won't work as you expect because the max is 100.

Comment: Edit: erased what I had before due to it being irrelevant now - thanks! Also, is there any way to show multiple pages in the same document, for example, returning pages 1-15 at the same time?

Comment: @John No unfortunately, you have to go one by one. Twitter has these limits in place due to the very high load they have being the popular site they are. If they allowed 15 pages the same time, that would be a lot of data to transfer, which adds up when you have as many users as they do.

Comment: atom/rss/xml support is being dropped from twitter API in march!

Answer (score 0):

My sugestion.
Make a request to your API and retrieve 100 results by time.
Use a loop to check if your result count is set to 100.
if true, do a new request to page 2.
test again and check the number of itens until the resultset is lower than 100.

Comment: Won't work reliably. If any tweets have to be removed from the response (because they are protected, or have been deleted), they are removed *after* the 100 is counted. So you may end up with less than 100 items in the result even if there's more left.

Comment: You're right, when I used this feature, I set a maximum value to determine if I would go to the next page.
For example, I made a check if the number of items was greater than 90 tweets, so I tried to go to page 2

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter Search API has changed, including in the naming of the parameters: for instance, **rpp** is now **count** and the **page** parameter was removed in favor of **max_id**, a parameter based on a timeline concept:

> "To use max_id correctly, an application’s first request to a
>   timeline endpoint should only specify a count. When processing this
>   and subsequent responses, keep track of the lowest ID received. This
>   ID should be passed as the value of the max_id parameter for the next
>   request, which will only return Tweets with IDs lower than or equal to
>   the value of the max_id parameter."

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/guides/working-with-timelines

The updated link to the Twitter search api is:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html

Remember that not all tweets are indexed and if you are using the non-commercial version, you are limited to a 7-day search.