# Can twitter search rss feed limit be increased

Tags: xml, api, rss, twitter

Is there any way to increase twitter search rss feed limit. URL - `http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=hello`

Currently only 15 feeds are shown... I need the output of all the results related to query.

Answer (score 1):

The limit cannot be increased but you can get additional results by using the page parameter as discussed here: [Twitter search API results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104435/twitter-search-api-results) and here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search

Edit: You can display more results on each page by using the "rpp" parameter up to 100. Like this: `http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=hello&rpp=100`. Using the page parameter will allow you to get up to 1500 results total.